# Limit with an indeterminate form

Tags: calculus

Here when we unite the denominators should we state the x cannot equal zero since we divide by it in the first term

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: $x$ is approaching $2$ right ,then what do you mean by it's $0$?

Answer (score 1):

The value of the function at $0$ should not matter. The question is asking for the $\lim_{x\to 2}$, so the function being undefined at zero has nothing to do with the limit.

Stating that $x \neq 0$ is also unnecessary, as this statement is implied in the simplified function,
$$y = \frac{-1}{2x}$$

If you meant that $x \neq 2$ should be mentioned, because the discontinuity at $x = 2$ is a removable discontinuity, the limit can still be found as $x$ **approaches** that value, so it is not relevant in the case of this limit. *Technically*, though, it should be mentioned that the function is undefined at $2$ once the discontinuity is removed.